# Angular2 ReactiveFormsModule Unexpected module

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, import

I have been working on my app. 
I want to use ReactiveFormsModule module but I am getting

> Error: Unexpected module 'ReactiveFormsModule' declared by the module 'AppModule'

I have installed angular/forms into my project but nothing seems to work. 
Any idea?

My component.ts file

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup, FormControl} from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-crm-search',
  templateUrl: './crm-search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./crm-search.component.css'],
})
export class CrmSearchComponent{
  constructor() {
  }

  userForm = new FormGroup({
    searchTerm: new FormControl()
  });

  onSubmit(){
    console.log(this.userForm.value());
  }
}
```

My app.module.ts

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import {AlertModule} from 'ng2-bootstrap';
import {Select2Module} from 'ng2-select2';
import {RoutingModule} from './routing.module';
import {ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';


import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {NavBarComponent} from './components/nav-bar/nav-bar.component';
import {IndexComponent} from './index/index.component';
import {CrmIndexComponent} from './crm/crm-index/crm-index.component';

import {CrmSearchComponent} from './crm/crm-search/crm-search.component';
import {CrmSearchResultComponent} from './crm/crm-search-result/crm-search-result.component';

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        NavBarComponent,
        IndexComponent,
        CrmIndexComponent,
        CrmSearchComponent,
        CrmSearchResultComponent,
        ReactiveFormsModule

    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        RoutingModule,
        Select2Module,
        [AlertModule.forRoot()]
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to add it to your `imports`, rather than your `declarations`